# doctest stop after import

Tags: python, import, doctest

im trying to run a `doctest` on my Python code.

im using this to run the `doctest`

```
import doctest
doctest.testfile("test.txt", verbose=True)
```

and the `test.txt` file looks like this:

```
print("hello")

hello
from filetotest import *

print("hello")

hello
```

my problem is that after the 3rd line `from filetotest import *` the doctest stops to run the doctest

```
Trying:

    print("hello")
Expecting:

    hello
ok
Trying:

    from filetotest import *

Expecting nothing
```

so after i try to import the functions from the `filetotest` the `doctest` dont try the rest in the file, what i want to do is test the functions in the `filetotest`.

what is wrong, why does it stop?

Comment: Using ".txt" as a file extension may be breaking Python's import system. Use ".py" instead.

Comment: hello! thanks for your answer! i dont think thats the problem as i can import my file containing the class for the code without problem